# Type error on vsc but still can be complied?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Maybe this was from the extensions I downloaded but previously, I did not have this issue. Something happened and now my files keep showing errors even though there shouldn't be.

[image]

This error occurs when I call a component that takes in props like comments

```
type Props = { 
    comments?: string
}
```

Since adding a `?` allows the prop to be undefined, I'm stumped on why this error appears. Please help!

Comment: The error happens right because you're allowing it to take the `undefined` type, which renders it incompatible with its counterpart. It isn't erroring because it actually was `undefined` at any given point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type Props = { 
    comments?: string
}
```

This means that Props may have comments prop or maybe not. So, if comments prop is passed to a react functional component then we can access it directly as it defined but if we don't pass the comments then comments would be undefined so if you try to access it then it will throw a compile-time error which is same as you have shown in the image.

**Solution**: Don't pass the comments if it is not defined

```
let props: Props = {};

if(food.comments){
 props.comments = food.comments;
}

<ReactComp {...props} />
```